# How do I contact a moderator?

Tags: support

In certain circumstances it can be useful to attract the attention of one of the moderators.  There are various ways of doing this, what are they?  Also, not all ways are equal: some require some reputation, what is this reputation level?

Comment: **Note:** I'm not asking this for myself!  My intention is that this get put in the unofficial faq: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/the-unofficial-tex-sx-faq

Answer (score 8):

- **Flag for moderator attention**. If you'd like to point the moderator's attention to an issue related to a particular question and answer, use the *Flag* button below every post. You might find the already predefined categories useful, but if not, use the free edit field to describe your problem. This is the method that would guarantee you the fastest reply. You only need 15 reputation in order to do this. Moderators can respond back through a message in your global inbox, or at certain isolated cases, through email.
- **Hang out in chat**. If a matter requires a lengthy discussion with back-and-forth posts, this is probably the most efficient way to do it. Be sure to address the moderator with @ before their screen name, so that they would get a notification even if not in chat currently. Moderators hang out in chat often, and there are also some old-time users which might be of assistance as well. You only need 20 reputation in order to join the chat room permanently, otherwise you are restricted to only 2 hours there <sup>[citation needed]</sup>.
- **Post a meta question**. If your issue concerns the TeX-SE community at large rather than only you personally, consider posting a question on [our meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/). Moderators monitor meta activity frequently, and will be able to respond in due time. You only need 5 reputation to do this.

How **NOT** to attract moderator attention:

- **Do not create questions, answers and comments, hijacking unrelated discussions.** These will be quickly closed as off-topic or thoroughly deleted, and a moderator might heed your call for attention with a gentle reminder to read the FAQ before posting in this manner. This only creates extra noise and work for everybody on the site, so avoid this practice and choose other venues to communicate your problem to the moderators.