# Is it possible to send a private message directly to the moderators?

Tags: support, moderation

Is it possible to complete a form on TeX.SE that can be sent directly (and privately) to moderators? If so, where can I do that?

Comment: To the downvoter: please, explain me what is the reason of the downvote?

Comment: No no no. I don't agree and I'm sure of it. I simply have a suspicion and I'm convinced that time is gentlemanly. You probably don't see the downvote.

Comment: @user49915 That the time (i.e. hours, or the passing of days) will give me justice.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/how-do-i-contact-a-moderator

Comment: @PauloCereda I want know the contacts that not exist into your link. For my opinion my question is not a duplicate but similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no private form to contact moderators. You may either:

- Flag material with a free-form comment to alert moderators to an issue
- Contact the StackOverflow staff directly about serious issues: https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: +1. In the meantime, thank you for your kind and timely reply. For the second option there is a link, an email where you can report the problem? I ask only and with such humility and sincerity to simply be quiet and serene. I don't ask for anything else.

Comment: I just sent the email to the link you forwarded to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano Note that Contact Us goes to staff, not to the local mods

Comment: Yes of course. I have seen the 2nd item "Contact the StackOverflow staff". Always thank you.

Comment: Did my question irritate anyone?